# Keep the selected tab when I refresh/back

Tags: javascript, html

I have set the first tab to be the default tab, everytime I go to another page and press the back button, it shows the default tab. How should I do to keep on the tab I just access?

HTML

```
        <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks active" onclick="chooseReportType(event, 'apple')">apple</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="chooseReportType(event, 'banana')">banana</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="chooseReportType(event, 'cat')">cat</button>
        </div>
```

JS

```
function chooseType(evt, Type) {
    
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(ReportType).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

}
```

Comment: You can use `window.localStorage`

Comment: You can set the query param in url and set tab as active accordingly.